Cant' Style Parks in Maputnik via OpenMapTiles
I am unable to figure out how to style parks in Maputnik.
Currently, they are all being subsumed into landuse-residential, and I believe I need to style them through leisure-parks, but am unable to figure out how. Could someone advise how this is done in Maputnik?

Maputnik applies a style to vector tiles. But the data needs to be in the tiles, and tiles are extremely flexible and vary wildly by setup. The tile schema will determine what layer the data is in (if the data you want is there at all). Could you update the question with info on where the tiles are coming from / how they are generated?
